# FactoMineR's MCA runs out of memory

Tags: r, memory

With the R package FactoMineR I'm trying to run a ACM in a big DataFrame (600000 observations, 31 variables).

I'm loading my DataFrame this way:

```
mydata = read.csv("/home/tom/Desktop/ACM/acm.csv")
```

I'm running my ACM this way:

```
res.mca <- MCA(mydata)
```

But I'm getting the following error message:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 2592.0 Gb
```

How can I run my ACM? Should I need to store my DataFrame in an other way?

Comment: Have you tried data.table package and fread?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel I don't think that will help since `MCA` throws the error. I'm not familiar with Multiple Correspondence Analysis, but I would wonder if my approach is sensible if I received this error.

Comment: what do you mean @Roland by "if my approach is sensible"?

Comment: The function is obviously not designed to handle your data (due to it's size, number of factor levels, ...). Possibly their is a problem with data import (numeric variables read in as factors) or the function is not designed to handle this kind of data, which might mean the statistical method is not appropriate for it.

Comment: You need to have categorical variables in order to perform MCA. Are the columns in your dataframe factors?

Comment: my variables are qualitative but the classes are integer, maybe it is considered as quantitative, any idea how can I set the variables as qualitative @GeorgeDontas